# Find differential relation by eliminating $\phi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A meridian $z$ vs $r$  in cylindrical coordinates of a surface of revolution makes angle $\psi$ with an arc $s$ drawn on it and tangent angle $\phi$ to axis of symmetry.

Constant $c_1$ and two relations

$$ \cos \phi \cos \psi   = r^2 c_1 \tag1 $$
$$ - \phi^{'}+ \frac{\cos \phi \sin^2 {\psi}}{r.\cos \psi  }= 2 c_1\cdot r \tag2 $$

( primed w.r.t. arc), please help in showing that:

$$ r \cdot \sin \psi= c_2 $$ 
where $c_2$ is a new constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answering the question.

Numerical integration yielded results with an image shown quite convincing to intuition although proof appeared tough at time of posting .. however kept on at it...

The result follows by eliminating $\phi^{'}$ between the given equations (1),(2) and differentials:

$$ r^{'}=\sin \phi \cos \psi; z^{'}=\cos \phi \cos \psi;\,r \theta ^{'}=\sin \psi; $$

Take logs Differentiate (1)

$$ \phi^{'}= \frac{\tan \psi^{'}}{r}-\frac{2\cos \phi \cos \psi}{ r^2 }\tag 3$$

Inserting $c_1$ from (1) into (2) and simplify

$$ \phi^{'}=\frac{ \cos\phi} {r \cos\psi} (1-3 \cos^{2}\psi) \tag4 $$

Equating RHS of (3) and (4) and simplifying we arrive at
$$\sin \phi - \cos \psi^2 \sin \phi + r \cos \psi \tan \psi \,\psi^{'}=0 \tag5$$

further simplifying,

$$ \sin \phi \sin \psi + r \psi^{'}=0;\,(r\sin \psi)^{'} = 0 \tag6 $$

$$ \rightarrow r\sin \psi = c_2 \tag7 $$

[image: Geodesics Balanced]